# Is there an unsigned integer type that will warn about negative literals?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Recent versions of `ghc` will warn you if an integer literal is outside a given type's range.  For example:

```
$ ghci
>>> let x = 330492039485 :: Data.Word.Word8
<interactive>:2:9: Warning:
    Literal 330492039485 is out of the GHC.Word.Word8 range 0..255
```

However, `ghc` will not warn about negative numeric literals for `Data.Word` types.  Instead, it underflows (intentionally, according to the documentation):

```
>>> let x = -1 :: Data.Word.Word8
>>> x
255
```

Are there any types that will warn about negative literals or is there a way I can create my own custom type that does warn?

Comment: Looking at the source for Data.Word, it looks like the warnings are built-in to the compiler.  There is `Panic` module in the hidden package ghc which looks like it can emit warnings, but that doesn't sound like a very optimal solution.

Comment: I've recently been wanting one or two 'subtypes' of Integer, namely Natural and Positive (and Positive is optional for me), which would ideally use the `mpn_` family of functions in GMP for their implementation. We have `Nat` at the type level but nothing at the value level, and that strikes me as weird, so I'm going to keep an eye on the responses!

Comment: As for your question, there's a distinction to be made: does `Word8` represent the integers modulo 256 (in which case the fact that `-1 == 255` is perfectly reasonable), or is it meant to represent the set `{0, ..., 255}` (in which case `-1 == 255` should be ill-typed)? It also ties in to the messy `Num` design; `(-)`, `negate` and `fromInteger` shouldn't be in there (let alone `abs` and `signum`!), but that's a different can of worms...

Comment: @yatima2975 I would also like subtypes of Double (or maybe Rational?). My use would be a Decibel type where math is defined logarithmically. I tried and failed to get this going in Julia. Probably not doable in Haskell either.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default, a literal like `-1` is desugared to `negate (fromInteger 1)`. There is however a language extension [`NegativeLiterals`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#negative-literals) that causes it to desugar as `fromInteger (-1)` instead. If you enable that you *do* get a warning:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Word
Prelude Data.Word> :set -W
Prelude Data.Word> :set -XNegativeLiterals
Prelude Data.Word> -1 :: Word

<interactive>:74:1: Warning:
    Literal -1 is out of the Word range 0..18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
Prelude Data.Word>
```

Alternatively, you could make your own type that redefined `negate`, but then you would presumably only get a runtime error.